# Gtk Drawing Area not always rendering when inside a scrolled window

Tags: gtk3, python3

I have a Drawing Area inside a Viewport inside a Scrolled Window. The image renders fine when the Drawing Area fits inside the Scrolled Window. But when i request a size larger than the Scrolled Window then the Drawing Area is not always redrawn when I scroll up or down, and the same happens when the parent window is resized. What happens is that I get an area of the right size inside the Scrolled Window, but it looks as if there is no Drawing Area inside, or as if there is nothing drawn on the Drawing Area, which sometimes flashes with the correct drawing on random positions of the scrollbars. I have connected a callback to the draw signal that prints " render" every time it gets called, and another callback to the value-change signal of the adjustments of the scrollbars that print "adj" to screen whenever they get scrolled. The terminal output is as follows

```
adj
adj
adj
adj
adj
1428919598 render
adj
adj
adj
```

So every time i see adj the canvas look blank, while it gets drawn correctly when i see <...> render. Hence by scrolling fast I get a flickering image. Any idea of what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was porting some code from gtk2 to gtk3. The problem turned out to be in the new signal "draw" which now replaces "expose-event". In the older version I had to create the context in the signal handler, but the new callback has it as one of the arguments, and it is that one that should be used.